# How does readline use compgen to get all applicable completions?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

I'm building an alternative to `readline` and would like to have tab completion in a similar way to how `readline` has tab completion. In `readline`, if you type `git <tab>` you get all the git subcommands as autocomplete options. But if you type `ls <tab>` you get files and directories. It's pretty clear how to get those individually by invoking `compgen` using one of it's options, but it's not clear how to invoke `compgen` and get the same set of completions that `readline` gives. Essentially completeing from all applicable sources. What option can I supply to get that behaviour?

Comment: This question is very unclear. `compgen` is a Bash command. GNU Readline gathers completions via a callback mechanism: a generator function installed by the application which returns one string at a time back to Readline. To see how Bash's internal completion callback(s) is/are related to the `compgen` command, you have to read the Bash sources. It could be that the callback arrangement between Bash and readline can do things that aren't doable via `compgen`.